# Best Code Repository for Web Project

Tags: version-control

I am starting to build a website, I need to know what it's the best option to manage my code and different versions of the same, any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Git. Though you're really just starting a holy war.

Comment: SVN. And I was going to say the same thing, just asking for a huge debate on here haha.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).